# R Markdown Presentation - Add Footnotes

Tags: rstudio, r-markdown

Here is my first couple of pages of my R Markdown presentation that I am trying to create.

```
Statistics 101
========================================================
author: ManiL
date: June 17, 2015

Review of Statistical Concepts
========================================================

Definition

- Statistics is the science of data collection, analysis and interpretation of results.
====================================================
```

I would like to add a footnote that will appear on every page.  I see suggestions online but would like to see an actual example.

Comment: Check this: http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/27777_55697c3a476640caa0ad2099fe914ae5.html#/3

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to my colleague Shibing, here is what I did.  I included the following at the top of my first slide above the title page which actually fixed the problem.  thanks to everyone for your time and support.

---

```
<style>

.footer {
    color: black; background: white;
    position: fixed; top: 90%;
    text-align:left; width:100%;
}

</style>

<div class="footer" style="margin-top;font-size:80%;"> 
Footer for every slide </div>
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Well if it means that you need a markdown then here it is .

```
# Statistics 101
**author: ManiL date: June 17, 2015**
## Review of Statistical Concepts
Definition
###- Statistics is the science of data collection, analysis and interpretation of results.
```

Hope This is the markdown you are looking for.

Comment: That's not what the question is about. He's looking for a footer for every slide of an RPresentation.